# Firefox and IE not downloading MP4 file from different origin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I've a case in which Chrome is working fine but firefox and IE not.

**Case:** I need to download an MP4 file from different origin using a button which is an anchor tag. Below is the code for it:

```
<a id="lnkDownloadVid" class="btn-download" href="www.downloadlink.com/downloadVideo.mp4" download="testdownload.mp4">
<span>DOWNLOAD ATV</span>
<span>
<img src="../App_Themes/Default/Images/example/download-icon.png" style="width: 15px;" />
</span>
</a>
```

My domain is **www.example.com** and I'm trying to download from **www.downloadlink.com** a video file named "downloadVideo.mp4".

**Issue** what I'm facing in firefox and IE is that instead of downloading it starts streaming the video, what my **need** is to download the video instead of streaming.

Can anyone have a solution either using **jquery** or **html5**?
I don't want to use server side because the video file size is huge (approx 100+ MB).